# Permutations with modifications in python

Tags: python, permutation

I am stuck on following problem:
there is normal permutation function:

```
def all_perms(elements):
    if len(elements) <=1:
        yield elements
    else:
        for perm in all_perms(elements[1:]):
            for i in range(len(elements)):
                yield perm[:i] + elements[0:1] + perm[i:]
```

Here I get as expected

```
for pz in all_perms([1,2,3]):
    print(pz)

[1, 2, 3]
[2, 1, 3]
[2, 3, 1]
[1, 3, 2]
[3, 1, 2]
[3, 2, 1]
```

Then I have simple reverse function:

```
def reverse(rx):
    return -rx
```

How could look function perm_rev(iterable) resulting in permutation assuming each element has to be reversed? Answer for [1,2] would be like this:

```
for pz in perm_rev([1,2]):
    print(pz)

[1,2]
[2,1]
[-1,2]
[1,-2]
[-2,1]
[2,-1]
[-1,-2]
[-2,-1]
```

Thank you!

Comment: @Martijn Pieters  and unutbu: Thank you, but I need to use reverse function (it is simplified here). Actually instead of reverse must be any function, which modifies element. Element could be a list.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import itertools as IT
def perm_rev(iterable):
    for grp in IT.product(*[[x, -x] for x in iterable]): # 1
        for item in IT.permutations(grp):                # 2
            yield item
```

For example,

```
In [46]: list(perm_rev([1,2]))
Out[46]: [(1, 2), (2, 1), (1, -2), (-2, 1), (-1, 2), (2, -1), (-1, -2), (-2, -1)]
```

1. For each `x` in `iterable`, `grp` selects either `x` or `-x`. For
   example,

   ```
   In [53]: list(IT.product([-1,1], [-2,2])) 
   Out[53]: [(-1, -2), (-1, 2), (1, -2), (1, 2)]
   ```
2. Then for each `grp`, generate the permutions of `grp`.

---

Note also that your `all_perms` could be written in terms of [itertools.permutations](http://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.permutations):

```
def all_perms(elements):
    return IT.permutations(elements)
```

The two are essentially the same (except for the order of the elements, and that `IT.permutations` returns an iterator instead of a list).

---

To generalize `perm_rev` to apply a function other than `reverse`, you could do this:

```
def reverse(x):
    return [x, -x]

def perm_rev(iterable, options):
    for grp in IT.product(*[options(x) for x in iterable]): 
        for item in IT.permutations(grp):                
            yield item
```

Then, call `perm_rev` like this:

```
In [58]: list(perm_rev([1,2], reverse))
Out[58]: [(1, 2), (2, 1), (1, -2), (-2, 1), (-1, 2), (2, -1), (-1, -2), (-2, -1)]
```

Answer (score 0):

Add in reversals in a generator function, with a [`itertools.product()` call](http://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.product):

```
def perm_rev(seq):
    for perm in permutations(seq):
        for prod in product(*((i, -i) for i in perm)):
            yield prod
```

Demo:

```
>>> for pz in perm_rev([1,2]):
...     print(pz)
... 
(1, 2)
(1, -2)
(-1, 2)
(-1, -2)
(2, 1)
(2, -1)
(-2, 1)
(-2, -1)
```

Comment: This includes `[1, -1]`